# Origins of Musical Slichos

Tags: music, provenance, selichot

I recently saw a sign in my community advertising in a (Orthodox) Shul for a musical accompanied Slichos (*with instruments*) on [Leil Slichos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leil_Selichot). When did such a practice originate? Was such a practice ever spoken about by poskim?

Comment: This is a new concept to me, somewhat. The only person I can think of who did a musical Selichot is Rabbi Seymour Rockoff, but I think he meant it as a joke (i.e., it wasn't the actual Selichot.) Though, with him, one can't really be sure what he did.

Comment: Carlbach did it.

Comment: @user6591 was there any Halachic motivation for it?

Comment: Carlbachian motivations. Whatever got him to do it and however people reacted to it, positively or negatively, and however it fit into the older fight between orthodox and reformed about music during services is a huge subject. I think I may have asked a question here once about instruments by havdala. It's just one of those things.